# Tracking Historical Firm Names

Tags: data

I am working on a project that requires me to track firms' name changes.

- The firms I am dealing with are international (a decent number of US firms, but also a sizeable number of European, Asian, and Latin American firms).
- I only need firm name histories between roughly 2000-22.

I have access to WRDS (Wharton Research Data Services). I have poked around Compustat North America/Global. I could be wrong, but it seems like they only give the most recent firm names.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

Your WRDS includes CRSP: https://wrds-www.wharton.upenn.edu/pages/grid-items/crsp-coverage/

In CRSP, given a security's permno, you just retrieve the history of name changes, cusip changes, etc..

However, in addition to name changes, you may need to deal with mergers and spin-offs that change the permno.

Also CRSP is north american centric. A database called Osiris, also in WRDS, may help with some non-US name changes.

Comment: This is an example of a  general strategy: (1) find a database that includes a unique permanent identifier (for CRSP this is permno) for all your companies (2) print all company names associated with that permanent ID